# opencv: iterate fast through pixel of a contour

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to iterate through the pixel in a polygon ( opencv contour ), to get some properties of the item( max. greyvalue, min. greyvalue, mean greyvalue, ... )
The question is, how to do this in the fastest possible way? ( I've to extract thousands of them )

In the opencv answers, there is an answer to this question (
http://answers.opencv.org/question/29693/fastest-method-to-loop-through-contour-pixels/ ), but unfortunately opencv is at the moment down for a while.

Does anyone know, what the suggested algorithm was? There are three algorithm, that comes to my mind.

1.) Extract Shape and do and-operator with the original image ( sounds too expensive )

2.) Perform flood fill like iteration ( sounds better but not perfect )

3.) Perform a sweep-plane triangulation-style algorithm (don't know exactly how to do this )

Have anyone another/better ideas? What do you think is the most promising/fastest algorithm.

Comment: "I want to iterate throw the pixel" - don't ! totally *not* the opencv way. better tell us: what are you trying to achieve in the end ?

Comment: I want some properties of the shape, like max. greyvalue, min. greyvale, histogram, ...

Comment: opencv is open source, have a look at the `drawContours` function (parameter set to `filled`) and instead of setting the pixel value, use it for your computation. This might be a good starting point. Depending on assumptions about your contours (e.g. they are small compared to the whole image size, etc) special algorithms or limitations to subimages etc might be better.

Answer (score 0):

according to:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://answers.opencv.org/question/29693/fastest-method-to-loop-through-contour-pixels/

there was no suggested answer ;)

In general I would compute `minBoundingRect` of your contour and perform how `drawContours` does (didn't check the open source code yet) to find all pixel within that contour (possibly some on/off pixel algorithm?!?).

In my own projects I just draw the contours in 8UC1 white and use it as a mask, which was sufficent for my tasks.